# how to prevent override of Page_Load method when using a custom base page class

Tags: c#, inheritance, webforms

I am developing an ASP.NET Webforms website using ASP.NET 4.5.
I have a master page that I use for my forms, but I want the page classes to inherit from another `SitePage` class, the code for which is below :

```
public abstract class SitePage : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // common logic here
        Page_LoadImpl(sender, e);
    }

    protected abstract void Page_LoadImpl(object sender, EventArgs e);
}
```

a page's class would then look like:

```
public partial class MyPage: SitePage
{
    protected override void Page_LoadImpl(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //page specific logic here
    }
}
```

I am coming from a Java background, how can i make my SitePage `Page_Load` method final, non-overridable? I know I can use Nested Master pages to achieve the same thing, but I don't want to redefine the page's content.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method is only overridable if it is marked with "virtual" or "abstract".

Your method "Page_Load" is NOT marked with those keywords so it is already non-overridable.

Comment: alright i see, but then i could put a 
     `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`
in the MyPage class. I guess that's treated as new method by default, hiding the one from BasePage, correct? in that case there's nothing i can do to prevent that, right?

Comment: That is 100% correct! The compiler will give a warning though. This warning can be suppressed by using the keyword "new" on the second Page_Load.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sealed`-keyword, which serves the same purpose as `final` in `Java`.

Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
class X
{
    protected virtual void F() { Console.WriteLine("X.F"); }
    protected virtual void F2() { Console.WriteLine("X.F2"); }
}
class Y : X
{
    sealed protected override void F() { Console.WriteLine("Y.F"); }
    protected override void F2() { Console.WriteLine("X.F3"); }
}
class Z : Y
{
    // Attempting to override F causes compiler error CS0239. 
    // protected override void F() { Console.WriteLine("C.F"); }

    // Overriding F2 is allowed. 
    protected override void F2() { Console.WriteLine("Z.F2"); }
}
```

Comment: I would, but Page_Load is not an override. From what i know sealed can only be used on overridden methods, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class SitePage : Page
{
    sealed protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // common logic here
        Page_LoadImpl(sender, e);
    }

    protected abstract void Page_LoadImpl(object sender, EventArgs e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override SupportAutoEvents.

protected sealed override bool SupportAutoEvents
{
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
}